# Why do I often get "ld returned 1 exited status" while I didn't find any process to kill in task manager?

Tags: c, linked-list, dev-c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct Node{
    struct Node * prior;
    char data;
    struct Node * next;
}Node;
Node* initNode(Node * head);
void display(Node * head);

int main() {
    Node * head=NULL;
    head=initNode(head);
    display(head);
    printf(":%s:",head->next->next->next->prior->data);
    return 0;
}
Node* initNode(Node * head){
    int i;
    char a[] = "0";

    head=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));

    head->prior=NULL;
    head->next=NULL;
    head->data=str(1);

    Node * list=head;
    for (i=2; i<=5; i++) {

        Node * body=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        body->prior=NULL;
        body->next=NULL;
        strcpy(a,str(i));
        strcat(a,"haha");
        body->data=a;


        list->next=body; 
        body->prior=list;

        list=list->next;
    }

    return head;
}
void display(Node * head){
    Node * temp=head;
    while (temp) {

        if (temp->next==NULL) {
            printf("%s\n",temp->data);
        }else{
            printf("%s <-> ",temp->data);
        }
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}
```

I use DEVC++ these days, and I always see this"D:\Dev-Cpp\项目2\collect2.exe  [Error] ld returned 1 exit status".
I looked at my task manager,but I did not find anything like"D:\Dev-Cpp\项目2\collect2.exe",I don't know if it's my code's problem.
What's wrong with my code? Thank you!:)

Comment: That tells you that the linker failed. There should be more error messages before that. Please show all the error messages. (Not sure why you expect to find anything in Task Manager as those processes will have terminated by that point).

Comment: `str(1);` What is that function?

Comment: https://postimg.cc/bdWyc85L   this is all the error messages. thank you

Comment: Don't post images or links to images.  Post the *text* in your question.  There's an "Edit" button for that reason.

Comment: It clearly tells you - `Undefined reference to 'str'`. When looking at errors always note the earlier ones and not just the last one.

Comment: Isn't str(1) type casting?  Oh, I confused it with python.

Comment: `sprintf(a, "%d", i);`

Comment: OT: `body->data=a;` should be `body->data=a[0]`;

Comment: "D:\Dev-Cpp\项目2\Makefile.win recipe for target '项目2.exe' failed" "D:\Dev-Cpp\项目2\collect2.exe [Error] ld returned 1 exit status" "D:\Dev-Cpp\项目2\main.o main.c:(.text+0xa7): undefined reference to `str'" how to correct them?

Comment: I showed you already. Replace `str` with the `sprintf` shown.

Comment: sprintf(a, "%d", i);
        strcat(a,"haha");
        body->data=a[0];
I changed it like this, but it still shows this error. May I have absence of changes?

Comment: "$(CC) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)"
this is the wrong place it shows

Comment: Which error is _this error_?